# Teamcity, Sonar and C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, sonarqube, teamcity

We are trying to use Sonar with TeamCity 8.1.5, SonarQube 5.1.2 and the SonarQube runner build step in TeamCity.

Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 are installed on the build agent.

The solution we try to analyse with SonarQube uses VS2013.

We have a build running where we have tried to use either the MSBuild or Visual Studio build step to build the solution, and then we have a  SonarQube runner step to perform the analysis.

Unless we specify the following as "Additional parameters" to the SonarQube build step:

```
-Dsonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=PathToDllFromSolution
-Dsonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop
-Dsonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe
```

we get errors like this:

```
 org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you wish to skip the analysis of not built projects, set the property "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".
    at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkMandatoryProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:105)
```

What do we have to do to avoid having to use the -D for assembly analysis?

Attaching screenshots of configuration:
[image: Build steps]
[image: SonarQube step]

Comment: Are you asking how to disable assembly analysis, or alternative methods to defining parameters?  Either way, from memory I think you can use individual teamcity system parameters on your build config - try defining some for each of the -D options, such as `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=PathToDllFromSolution` etc

Comment: It was about alternative methods to define parameters. When we upgraded to SonarQube 5.3, it worked without all the special parameters.

Answer (score 4):

We're building with MSBuild, our build steps are the following and we do not encounter these issues using SQ 5.1.2 & TC 9.1.3, but I do not think that it is an TC issue.

[image: Build steps]

[image: MSBuild]

[image: Tests]

[image: Sonar]

Comment: Thank you for your screenshots here! You run DotCover first to use the report in the SonarQube step, or is that for TC display?

Comment: This is just for TC display.

Comment: Where do the source location and tests location actually refer to, compared to your checkout directory? I can't really see the `build file path` in your msBuild config, so I am wondering if, for example, `DDL/Release` is self-generated or something..

Comment: Got it working. My app was in the root directory of the checkout dir. I had to provider `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%` for Source location.

Answer (score 1):

We upgraded to the latest version of SonarQube (5.3) and it does now work with TeamCity.

Comment: so you mean you get your nunit + dotcover results in sonarcube? if yes, what all settings you needed to make to do this?